# Read table from Web using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and am working to extract data from website https://www.screener.in/company/ABB/consolidated/ on a particular table (the last table which is ***Shareholding Pattern***)

I'm using BeautifulSoup library for this but I do not know how to go about it.

So far, here below is my code snippet. am failing to pick the right table due to the fact that the page has multiple tables and all tables share common classes and IDs which makes it difficult for me to filter for the one table I want.

```
import requests import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url = "https://www.screener.in/company/ABB/consolidated/"

r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"html.parser")
# print(soup)
#data_table = soup.find('table', class_ = "data-table")
# print(data_table) table_needed = soup.find("<h2>ShareholdingPattern</h2>")
#sub = table_needed.contents[0] print(table_needed)
```

Comment: You can import pandas and use `read_html(requests.get("Yourwebsite.com").text)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `requests` and `pandas`. Grab the last table and dump it to a `.csv` file.

Here's how:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_html(
    requests.get("https://www.screener.in/company/ABB/consolidated/").text,
    flavor="bs4",
)
df[-1].to_csv("last_table.csv", index=False)
```

Output from a `.csv` file:

[image]

Comment: dear baduker, thank you for the answer and the great idea to user pandas in such a great manner.!  glad to see such great application of pandas here. Many thanks alot for your great work. regards

Comment: Thank you, this solution works but can you please explain how it works. I do not see anywhere specifying the table, yet it pulls the exact table I want @baduker

Comment: Since you want the last table the `df[-1]` uses `indexing` to grab the first table from the end of the array. That's your table.

Comment: @baduker I need another help. How can I select specific columns, (i.e. last 2 columns). I added index_col but it doesn't work. ***df = pd.read_html(
        requests.get("https://www.screener.in/company/ABB/consolidated/").text, index_col=-2,
        flavor="bs4",
    )***